# Why Linear regression using Numworks calculator doest give exact result

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, linear-regression, calculator

I tried to do a simple linear regression using the "Numworks" calculator and unless I add many more data points or add a point where x=0 it doesn't give me the correct equation.

Could someone explain why is the equation

> y = 2*x -1.776356839e-15

instead of

> y = 2*x + 0

Is it because of the linear regression algorithm they use.

If this is the case shouldn't it still work for such a simple equation ?

I found the c++ code the calculator is using for linear model
https://github.com/numworks/epsilon/blob/master/apps/shared/linear_regression_store.cpp#L87

The code seem to do the following steps:

```
x = {1, 2, 3}
y = {2, 4, 6}
slope = Covariance[x, y]  / Variance[x]
intercept = Mean[y] - slope * Mean[x]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: it's just how floating point arithmetic works, unfortunately

Comment: I understand that because of float calculation dont have perfect precision. But other calculator seem to get the perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

That term,
1.776356839e-15,
is almost exactly
$2^{-49}$.
This suggests roundoff error.

If you can look at the
statistics for the
regression calculation
($\sum x, \sum y, \sum xy$),
and compare the results
to the
exact result,
perhaps you can see
where the roundoff occurs.

Comment: right but other calculator Ex: Desmos are giving the exact result see:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/daeupqyfew
 How is this possible?

Comment: You need to look at the formulas used.